# Connection between keyboard and screen in laptop

Tags: laptop, display, keyboard

I know this may sound silly but I just want to know how the `two parts - the display and the keyboard` of laptops are connected because I see only two `hinges` that are holding them??I am just curious to know it

I apologize if this question is `duplicate` or `off-topic` for this site..if its `off-topic` maybe someone should migrate it to related site!!

Comment: I think it depends on the laptop. Sometimes there are also cables for microphone, webcam and other sensors. Do you have a specific model in mind?

Comment: `model` means in what sense??

Comment: What specific laptop model?

Comment: i am using `SONY-VAIO`..but i think this is common in all laptop and not `model` specific..i think the answer below is appropriate to some extent..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one of the hinges is probably wide enough to contain a ribbon cable.
Here's an example where the ribbon cable connects to the middle of the display:

[image: pic]

Comment: although the `width` of two hinges are same but i think your answer is appropriate..there must be some cord that is connecting

Comment: Thanks rock -- Here's a teardown site showing a Vaio: http://forum.notebookreview.com/sony/274083-photos-taking-vaio-z-apart.html Of course, there are many different kinds of Vaio, but in the pictures you can see a ribbon cable connecting into one of the hinges.